# sequence: use of stirling formula

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to use the Sterling formula which says that:

$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{n!}{\sqrt{2*\pi}n^{n+1/2}*e^{-n}}=1$

I want to use it to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(n!)^{1/n}=\infty$. However, there is one thing I have to do, which I do not have the justification for, can it be justified?, here it is:

$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(n!)^{1/n}=lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(n!)^{1/n}\dfrac{(\sqrt{2*\pi}n^{n+1/2}*e^{-n})^{1/n}}{(\sqrt{2*\pi}n^{n+1/2}*e^{-n})^{1/n}}$

$=lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\dfrac{n!}{\sqrt{2*\pi}n^{n+1/2}*e^{-n}}\right)^{1/n}*(\sqrt{2*\pi}n^{n+1/2}*e^{-n})^{1/n}$.

Now comes my problem.  It is easy to see that this expression goes to infinity if we know that:

$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\dfrac{n!}{\sqrt{2*\pi}n^{n+1/2}*e^{-n}}\right)^{1/n}=1$. But do we nececarrily know that even though what is inside that parenthesis goes to 1?

I guess a similar question is that if $a_n\rightarrow K, K>0$, then $(a_n)^{1/n}\rightarrow 1$?, but is this really obvious?, if so, can you please show me a delta-epsilon proof of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather make an estimate, and worry about limits later.

Assuming the Stirling formula, we find that if $n$ is large enough, then 
$$n!\gt \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+1/2} e^{-n}\gt n^ne^{-n}.$$
Taking $n$-th roots, we find that if $n$ is large enough then
$$(n!)^{1/n}\gt \frac{n}{e}.$$
This settles the question.

**Remark:** The Stirling formula is overkill. Note that 
$$(n!)^2 =[(n)(1)][(n-1)(2)][(n-3)(3)]\cdots [(1)(n)].$$
The products $(n-k)(k)$ are all $\ge n$. It follows that $n!\ge n^{n/2}$, and therefore $(n!)^{1/n}\ge n^{1/2}$.

Comment: Thank you, but I got very curious about the fact that if $a_n \rightarrow K$, then $(a_n)^{1/n} \rightarrow 1$?. Would you say that you can say this because $K^0=1$, is that legal?

Comment: I would rather give a more formal argument, which one can do using the Bernoulli Inequality. (I am assuming naturally that $K\ne 0$.) But in this case the intuition is right, and one can write a justification as follows: The function $y^x$ is *continuous* at $x=0$ for any $y\gt 0$.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. But it doesn't follow from any standard limit theorems right?, because in the standard limit theorems you could just set x=0, if y was constant, but in our case y is not constant so it doesn't work? That was my main problem actually, if this was something that should have followed from the standard theorems or not.

Comment: I was using continuity of a *two* variable function.

Comment: Oh!, that was extremely smart. Then I guess that proof is rigorous if you just transfer the problem to two-dimensions, and use the theorem that says that if a function is continuous then limit value of the function sequence is the function value of the limit value of the sequence, and you consider the sequence $(a_n,1/n)$? I've never seen this trick before.

Comment: However, one can view the process as shifting the burden. from proving the result directly by a Bernoulli inequality argument, to proving continuity of a certain two-variable function. The positive thing is that we need general continuity facts anyway, for other purposes.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: $(n!)^{1/n}\gt \frac{n}{e}$ seems to be true for any $n \geq 0$. Am I wrong somewhere ? Cheers.

Comment: I did not want to bother with a tight bound, so gave away a lot in order to get what was needed quickly from the limit statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is sort of obvious. Assume that $K\ge1$, then for any $\epsilon>0$, there is $N$ such that
$$(1+\epsilon)^n\ge 1+n\epsilon>K\text{ for }n\ge N.$$
What's less obvious is $n^{1/n}\to 1$.

Comment: I am not sure how that works? Does it show that for any $\epsilon$ there is an N, so that if $n \ge N$ then $|a_n^{1/n}-1|< \epsilon$?

Comment: Yes, for example $K-1<a_n<K+1$ when $K$ is large.